# Second route returns page not found

Tags: symfony

Controller:

```
/**
     * @Route("/project/", defaults={"id" = 1})
     * @Route("/project/{$id}")
     */
    public function indexAction($id){

    $project = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('Portfolio:Project')
        ->find($id);

    return $this->render('project.html.twig', array('project' => $project));
}
```

whenever i go to /project/ it works fine, but when i go to /project/5(it exist).
I get No route found for "GET /project/5"

Comment: Can you post the entire function?

Comment: Yes, you can see it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two separate annotations. Just one annotation as given below is enough

```
/**
 * @Route("/project/{id}", defaults={"id" = 1})
 */
```

Note that the $ sign is not required.

Answer (score 0):

May be one route for your purpose is enough?

Something like this

```
@Route("/project/{$id}", defaults={"id" = 1})
```